# Incorrect Russian character in xelatex CMU Concrete

Tags: fonts, xetex

MWE in XeLaTex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
Б\'{о}льший №
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The same code in ordinary LaTeX is correct:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
Б\'{о}льший №
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the cause? Font?

***Update about font not found***

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{noto}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif} % <- Error
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Б\'{о}льший №\\
\textsf{Sans serif text}\\
{\tt True type text}
\end{document}
```

**Update with CMU Concrete font**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\tracinglostchars=2
\babelfont{rm}[Script=Cyrillic, Language=Russian]{CMU Concrete}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}[Script=Cyrillic, Language=Russian]
Б\'{о}льший №
\end{document}
```

Still the same:

[image]

Comment: That's a font problem, if you use a font that supports different languages, like [Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) (`\usepackage{noto-serif}`) the text appears as expected.

Comment: your title says cmu  concrete but you don't load that font so you get latin modern (which doesn't cover Cyrillic at all) and you don't get the output you show?  For your updated example using Noto, that is a freely available font you can install it if you do not have it available

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but even if I try CMU concrete, I still get the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a font, that properly supports the languages, you are using. Here is a solution with  [Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{noto-serif}
\usepackage{noto-sans}
\usepackage{noto-mono}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

  \textrm{Б\'{о}льший №}
  \textsf{Б\'{о}льший №}
  \texttt{Б\'{о}льший №}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show how to use Not? I liked it. To set all types of fonts: rm, sf and tt?

Comment: And what are the names of the fonts? I tried `\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}`, but it can't find. Or maybe, it's not good for monospace?

Comment: I was adding "noto" :-).....successively :-) +1

Comment: I added sans and mono

Comment: @Sebastiano - Why did you delete your answer? I liked the `fontspec` approach. Not all fonts come as a package for all engines...

Comment: @DG' I have done a mistake clicking on delete :-( excuse me:-( Now there is my answer.

Comment: Since the OP was using XeLaTeX, it would be a good idea to show how to get `Script=Cyrillic`. And also `Language=Russian`, since some Cyrillic fonts default to Bulgarian letters.

Comment: Also, the requested font, CMU Concrete, works just fine.

Answer (score 8):

You didn’t actually load CMU Concrete.  This MWE works fine in TeX Live 2020:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\tracinglostchars=2
\babelfont{rm}{CMU Concrete}

\begin{document}
Б\'{о}льший №
\end{document}
```

[image: CMU Concrete sample]

One advantage `\babelfont` has over the other approaches is that `babel` will load the font with `Script=Cyrillic` and `Language=Russian`, and switch to them whenever you select the Russian language.  On LuaLaTeX, you could even switch automatically whenever you type in Cyrillic, with no other commands.

Cyrillic is enough like Latin that you can often get by with the default settings, but some fonts will give you Bulgarian letters instead of Russian unless you select the language as an OpenType font feature.

Comment: It is impossible not give you an upvoted to your answer. :-)

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me: gives empty squares.

Comment: @Davislor Can you show, how to get `Script=Cyrillic` and `Language=Russian`?

Comment: @user4035 I did. The `\babelfont` command takes care of that. With `polyglossia`, it would be something like `\newfontfamily\russianfont{CMU Concrete}[Scale=Matchlowercase, Script=Cyrillic, Language=Russian]`.

Comment: @user4035 Or, if your document is all in Russian, you could `\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}[Script=Cyrillic, Language=Russian]`.

Answer (score 4):

I think that being in `XeLaTeX` and the characters are in unicode...it is necessary to use,

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial} %<---- a random set of characters.
```

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\begin{document}
Б\'{о}льший №
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `Noto Serif`,

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\begin{document}
Б\'{о}льший №
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you try Noto? I liked it. To set all types of fonts: rm, sf and tt?

Comment: @user4035 Yes of course, hoping to find the solution :-)

Comment: `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Noto Serif}` doesn't work for me. I used `\usepackage{noto}`, and it worked for rm, sf and tt fonts.

Comment: @user4035 Try to delete [Ligatures=TeX] if it works correctly.

Comment: Nope, still `Package fontspec Error: The font "Noto Serif" cannot be found.`. Maybe, it's not needed at all? I'll update the question, so you could reproduce.

Comment: @user4035 Ok, in my updated version of MikTeX all work correctly. Don't worry :-)

Comment: Ahh, TeX Live 2020, Linux Slackware here.

Comment: Maybe, you have it installed in OS?

Comment: OS w7 32-bit (2004).....I am using an old device...but it is like the light :-)

Comment: The `noto` package should install TrueType versions of the font family. [The font’s download page is here.](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-lgc)

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce your picture from the first example you give and just the last glyph appears, because it is present in Latin Modern Roman.

On the other hand, the following code reproduces the font (CMU Concrete) with no strange box, both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{CMU Concrete}[Script=Cyrillic]

\begin{document}

Б\'{о}льший №

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me your code shows the boxes. `$ xelatex -v
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
`, Linux Slackware 14.2. Why such differences?

Comment: @user4035 Possibly the fonts?

Comment: "Possibly the fonts?" - how to fix? This font was shipped with Latex, and I didn't install it.